# convert C source to Java source? preferably for windows

Tags: java, c, windows

i'm looking for something that'd convert C source code into java source code.

Preferably I shouldn't have to have any C or java compiler or JVM on my system, I just want to run the program.. give it a C file, and have it converted to java source code.

Preferably the code should function the same!!  But I at least want the tool to make an attempt!

Here are the errors from c2j
http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1593/aavp.jpg

Comment: And if someone has the same for COBOL to Java conversion, that would make many banks very happy :-)

Comment: I think your question title is backwards...

Comment: @Matt Joiner   i'm not porting I just know java and don't currently know c,  and to understand some code I want to see it in java!

Comment: @benoit you mean the banks actually have all the cobol source code at hand? ;)

Comment: @barlop Actually C is simple language, and don't have big STD lib. So if you only need to learn C then go ahead and try converter, but if you use Java library, then you're screwed, or you'll have to somehow port it to C too

Comment: If you take C, and strip out anything that doesn't have an equivalent in Java (pointers, etc) you're pretty much left with Java since basically all you have left are the simple operators (which, for the most part, do the same thing).  Maybe you could post the C example and we could help you understand what it does?

Comment: There was an old joke about the FAQ "How do I convert Fortran to C".  The answer was "rm *.f will convert all your crappy Fortran programs into free disk blocks that you can use to write good C programs on".

Comment: @MBO this wouldn't need anything in the java library. the C is basic, I just don't know c well enough to read it. And I don't need to run it. Just read it. I want to read it in java source.

Comment: If you can read Java, you can probably read C enough for your purposes. Areas where you might have to learn more (pointers etc) don't have a proper translation into Java anyway so your translator wouldn't help much there.

Comment: There are indeed pointers.  I've just updated my question with a screenshot of an attempt and the errors it gives of why it won't. maybe some can be resolved.

Comment: You want to port Java to C, not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be challenging to convert a C program into Java automatically. The differences between C and Java means that you can't just convert line by line. A few example:

- C does not support classes, but classes are a fundamental concept of Java.
- C has a huge pointer syntax, Java doesn't.

There are many, many differences between C and Java, so I doubt that any program will do a good job of the conversion.

That said, there are a few project thats attempt this:

http://www.soften.ktu.lt/~stonis/c2java/

http://tech.novosoft-us.com/product_c2j.jsp

Comment: I've updated with a screenshot with errors I get  when I try with c2j.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as Java you will have to have a JVM!

As for translation, try looking at [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/).

**EDIT:** Your title says one thing, your question asks the opposite. This answers the question C → Java question you originally asked.

Comment: NestedVM says "NestedVM provides binary translation for Java Bytecode."  I don't want binary translation, I want to read source code!!  I don't even need to run it

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it but here is a [link](http://tech.novosoft-us.com/product_c2j.jsp) to a tool that claims to do what you want.

Comment: I tried it  on sed.c but it gave errors like  no sed.h and  selinux/selinux.h

Comment: "November 11, 2001 - Release v1.0" and nothing obvious changed since!

Comment: Do you have the header files? I suspect it's going to look in the same directory as the source unless it can read the INCLUDE environment variable.

Comment: @Paul: Never claimed it was current but I doubt any developments in Java would have meant there was a need to actively update this tool. It's a crazy concept to start with for the very reasons given by @Computerish.

Comment: @Lazarus  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/execute.c  I was just trying to feed it that.. I called it sed.c  What should I be doing?  I want to see sed in java!

Comment: @Lazarus I see.. i'll just go to the parent directory of that and put all those files in a directory on my computer and feed it to the c2j program and see how it goes..

Comment: @Barlop, that file is not going to translate well. Lots of use of pointers, memory cooying etc. On the good side, you wouldn't have to learn much C to be able to read and understand it. Learning C to be able read programs generally isn't too hard either

Comment: @barlop: @Paul is right, you'd be better off with a copy of Kernighan and Richie (http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628). Anything that you can't read easily in C really isn't going to translate well into Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run it, but just read and understand it, you'd better ask a C developer to explain you...
Automatic tools will always produce badly written code and hard to read.

As suggested in the comments, if the code is small, you can also post it here so we can help you understand.